# How to crop a bitmap in particular size in center programatically

Tags: java, android, bitmap, crop

I am creating a map based application, I wanted to programatically crop the screenshot that is taken, in fixed sizes.

- LDPI - 156.75 x 86.25 px
- MDPI - 209 x 115 px
- HDPI - 313.50 x 172.50 px
- xHDPI - 418 x 230 px

It should be a center crop. I am not able to create an algorithm for the same. Also, I dont know the co-ordinate system in Android for 2-d Drawings. Any kind of help would be appreciated. :) Thx

[image]

Answer (score 0):

//YOU need to convert `px to dp` to workin all the density

```
 public static int pxToDp(Context context, float px) {
        if (context == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return (int) (px / context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }
```

Comment: I have the DP with me ... its 209x115 dp